# Fast way to loop through 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I am using a noise library to generate 2D Perlin noise based on the index of an array.

Currently, I am looping through the x, y indices and calling the function for each set of indices. Is there a faster way to do this in numpy.

```py
import numpy as np
import noise

def func(x, y, a, b, T):
    return noise.pnoise3(x/a, y/b, T)
```

What I want to do is assign the result of this function to the x, y indices of a 2D array. What i am doing currently is:

```py
n = np.empty(a, b)

for ix, iy in np.ndindex((a, b)):
    n[ix, iy] = func(ix, iy, a, b, T)
```

The expected result is an [a x b] array willed with noise values evaluated at those points.

Is there a faster way I can do this whilst still using the noise library?

Comment: You may be able to put it into a dataframe and then use `map.apply(func)` to generate your values.

Comment: If you have to call `func` once for each 'point', there isn't much that the iteration mechanism can do to speed it up.